# How can I update a input using a div click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following [code](http://jsfiddle.net/pN3eT/2/) in my web page, where I need to click on the input field and add values using the number pad provided! I use a script to clear the default values from the input when the focus comes to it, but I'm unable to add the values by clicking on the number pad since when I click on an element the focus comes from the input to the clicked number element. How can I resolve this issue. I tried the following code, but it doesn't show the number in the input.

```
var lastFocus;

$("#test").click(function(e) {
    // do whatever you want here
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#results").append(e.html());
    if (lastFocus) {
        $("#results").append("setting focus back<br>");
        setTimeout(function() {lastFocus.focus()}, 1);
    }
    return(false);
});


$("textarea").blur(function() {
    lastFocus = this;
    $("#results").append("textarea lost focus<br>");
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I notice is your selector for the number buttons is wrong

```
$('num-button').click(function(e){
```

Your buttons have a *class* of `num-button` so you need a dot before the class name in the selector:

```
$('.num-button').click(function(e){
```

Secondly, your fiddle was never setting `lastFocus` so be sure to add this:

```
$('input').focus(function() {
    lastFocus = this;
    ...
```

Thirdly, you add/remove the watermark when entering the field, but ot when trying to add numbers to it (that would result in "Watermark-text123" if you clicked 1, then 2 then 3).

So, encalpsulate your functionality in a function:

```
function addOrRemoveWatermark(elem)
{
    if($(elem).val() == $(elem).data('default_val') || !$(elem).data('default_val')) {
        $(elem).data('default_val', $(elem).val());
        $(elem).val('');
    }
}
```

And call that both when entering the cell, and when clicking the numbers:

```
$('input').focus(function() {
        lastFocus = this;
        addOrRemoveWatermark(this);
});
```

and:

```
$('.num-button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    addOrRemoveWatermark(lastFocus);
    $(lastFocus).val($(lastFocus).val() + $(this).children('span').html());
});
```

You'll see another change above - you dont want to use `append` when appends an *element*, you want to just concatenate the string with the value of the button clicked.

Here's a working branch of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/Zrhze/

Comment: This was a good answer! :) But there is a simple issue! even when I click on a NaN element, it adds the value! can you suggest me a way to prevent this! Thank you!

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri - What is a "NaN element"?

Comment: The "DONE" Element & "DEL" element! :)

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri - ah, I see. Easy, just give them a different class and handle them differently!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var default_val = '';

$('input').focus(function() {
    lastFocus = $(this);
    if($(this).val() == $(this).data('default_val') || !$(this).data('default_val')) {
        $(this).data('default_val', $(this).val());
        $(this).val('');
    }
});

$('input').blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') $(this).val($(this).data('default_val'));
});

var lastFocus;

$('.num-button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var text = $(e.target).text();
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(text))) {
        lastFocus.val(lastFocus.val() + text);
    }
});
```

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mgechev/pN3eT/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

Add the following function:

```
$('.num-button').live( 'click', 'span', function() {
    $currObj.focus();
    $currObj.val( $currObj.val() + $(this).text().trim() );
});
```

Also, add the following variable to global scope:

```
$currObj = '';
```

Here is the working link: http://jsfiddle.net/pN3eT/7/

### EDIT

Based on comment, you wouldn't be needing the var `lastFocus` and subsequent code.

The updated fiddle lies here http://jsfiddle.net/pN3eT/28/

Comment: You missed something on the append method when clicking a number, you forgot to change lastFocus to your new variable $currObj, the last focused input is not keeped :)